# Spring boot thymeleaf (field.hasError always false)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am building a web application and as part of my application, I am using Spring boot with Thymeleaf.

Spring version: 2.5.6, JDK: 17

When I try to submit form with some expected errors in input, the binding result identifies the errors and prints in the controller but in Thymeleaf when I check for errors nothing shows up.

**POM.XML**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unknown
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.sql.init.mode=never

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.org.thymeleaf=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.boot=ERROR
```

HMTL with Thymeleaf:

```
<form class="row mb-0" action="#" th:action="@{/post}" th:object="${formData}" method="post">

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="name">Name <small>*</small></label>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}" class="validation-message"></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" th:field="*{name}" class="sm-form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="email">Email <small>*</small></label>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}" class="validation-message"></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}" class="sm-form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('phone')}" th:errors="*{phone}" class="validation-message"></label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" th:field="*{phone}" class="sm-form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="service">Services</label>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('service')}" th:errors="*{service}" class="validation-message"></label>
        <select id="service" class="sm-form-control" th:field="*{service}" >
            <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
            <option th:each="service : ${T(com.utterlydesi.web.constant.Service).values()}"
                    th:value="${service}"
                    th:text="${service}">service
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col-12 form-group">
        <label for="title">Title <small>*</small></label>
        <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}"></div>
        <input type="text" id="title" th:field="*{title}" class="sm-form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 form-group">
        <label for="description">Description <small>*</small></label>
        <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('description')}" th:errors="*{description}"></div>
        <textarea class="required sm-form-control" id="description" name="template-contactform-message" rows="6" cols="30" th:field="*{description}"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 form-group">
        <button class="button button-3d m-0" type="submit" id="add-post-submit" value="submit" th:text="Submit"></button>
    </div>


    <div th:if="${result != null}">
        <span class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" th:utext="${result}"></span>
    </div>

    <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
        <li th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${error}">error</li>
    </ul>

    <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}">
        <li th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('global')}" th:text="${error}">error</li>
    </ul>

</form>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PostController {

    @GetMapping(value = {"/post"})
    public String post(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("formData", new PostAdd());
        return "post";
    }

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public String addPost(@ModelAttribute("formData") @Valid PostAdd formData, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        try {
            System.out.println(formData.toString());
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                System.out.println("2");
                System.out.println(bindingResult.hasErrors() + " " + bindingResult.hasFieldErrors("description"));
                System.out.println(model.asMap());
                model.addAttribute("result", "There was an issue with registration. Please corrected the fields highlighted in red");
                return "post";
            } else {
                System.out.println("3");
                //model.addAttribute(POST_ADD_OBJ_KEY, new PostAdd());
                //model.addAttribute("result", "Post added successfully");
            }

            System.out.println(bindingResult.hasErrors() + " " + bindingResult.hasFieldErrors("description"));
            return "redirect:/index";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/index";
        }
    }

    public PostController() {

    }
}
```

PostAdd.java

```
@Data
public class PostAdd {

    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a name")
    private String name;

    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;

    @Length(min = 10, message = "*Your phone number must have at least 10 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a valid phone number")
    private String phone;

    @NotNull(message = "*Please select a valid service")
    private Service service;

    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Please add a more descriptive title")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a title")
    private String title;

    @Length(min = 100, message = "*Please make your description more descriptive. At least 100 characters is required")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please enter description")
    private String description;
}
```

SOP output from controller:

```
PostAdd(name=First Middle Last, email=fml@gmail.com, phone=11111111111, service=null, title=11, description=111)
2
true true
{formData=PostAdd(name=First Middle Last, email=fml@gmail.com, phone=10123456789, service=null, title=11, description=111), org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.formData=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
Field error in object 'formData' on field 'description': rejected value [111]; codes [Length.formData.description,Length.description,Length.java.lang.String,Length]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [formData.description,description]; arguments []; default message [description],2147483647,100]; default message [*Please make your description more descriptive. At least 100 characters is required]
Field error in object 'formData' on field 'service': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.formData.service,NotNull.service,NotNull.com.utterlydesi.web.constant.Service,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [formData.service,service]; arguments []; default message [service]]; default message [*Please select a valid service]
Field error in object 'formData' on field 'title': rejected value [11]; codes [Length.formData.title,Length.title,Length.java.lang.String,Length]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [formData.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title],2147483647,5]; default message [*Please add a more descriptive title]}
```

What I have tried so far based on some other posts I have seen on Stackoverflow?

- Downgrade to JDK 8
- Downgrade to Spring boot less than 2.3.0
- Add @EnableWebMVC
- Replaced @PostMapping with @RequestMapping
- Switched places of @Valid with @ModelAttribute

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong at first sight. Maybe you can create a sample project on GitHub that shows the issue?

Comment: I will try to create one as soon as I get chance